# Break Table Cell Content when max-width is reached

Tags: css, html-table, css-tables

I have a HTML table like this:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width:40vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td class="block">1</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
      <td class="block">This should be a text that breaks after 200px Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The result:

[image: The rendered HTML/CSS]

The problem is, that the text should wrap when the `max-width` is reached. I know `white-space: nowrap` causes this problem, but without that the text wraps before `max-width` is reached.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this post may be outdated, but I'd still like to share an alternative method I use for my data table. Instead of directly placing the content within the tags, I wrap it with a element and apply the following CSS properties: `max-width: 100%; width: max-content;`.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 350px;
}

div {
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <div>This is a long text</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>short</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Normal</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>This is a long text</div>
    </td>
    <td class="long">
      <div>Sometimes very long text could appear that should break so the table does not get way too wide
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nk5rc4ux/)**

```
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width:40vw;
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

Add `white-space: pre-wrap` in `td` or remove `white-space: nowrap` in `table`

Can you add `span` tag in `td` to achieve this output?

```
span {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

**[JsFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/nk5rc4ux/1/)**

But, you had set `width:100%` in your `table`. I have set it in **px** like this `width:1500px`. If you set **100% width** in table, remaining columns will wrap those text before reaching its max-width.

**[JsFiddle 2 with Width:100%](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh4wur2f/)**

You can check the above fiddle, I have set `width:100%` in `table` and removed last 2 columns. Now, lengthy text column will adapt to `40vw` and remaining columns won't pre-wrap the text. So, it depends upon your parent table width also.

Comment: I clarified the question: The problem is, that the text should *not* wrap before `max-width` is reached

Comment: @Koopakiller Can you check my 2nd fiddle?

Comment: That's not what I want...I would like to see the table as small as possible but if neccesarry growing up to a `max-width` in each column depending on the `vw`. Means: I don't know anything about the table-contents but the user should be able to read the content as easy as possible which means I don't like to specify a width of a table I don't know how many columns it has

Answer (score 0):

since you have `white-space: nowrap;` it will not break but you can add class to the `td` which you want to break hope this helps you thanks.

```
.no-white-space{
white-space: normal;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width:40vw;
}

.no-white-space{
white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="block">1</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
      <td class="block no-white-space">This should be a text that breaks after 200px Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
      <td class="block">A table cell content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to avoid that I have to process the text in any way. Adding another class is not so easy to implement then a plain CSS solution

Comment: @Koopakiller, this answer doesn't appear to process the text. What does your second sentence mean? Adding a class is a plain CSS solution.

Comment: I don't know anything about the cell contents, especially the length of the texts that's why I cannot add a class without further processing of the texts